# Problemas al codificar una serie de Taylor (logaritmo natural)

Tags: c++

Tengo un pequeño problema con la serie de *Taylor*. Para ser exactos con la de logaritmo natural. Por lo que me e dado cuenta, es porque en el divisor crece de forma brutal y la escritura de palabra no me da para mas, lo he intentado con tipos de datos `long long` pero ni aún así me ayuda a resolver el problema.

Código *C++*:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

double log_mac(double);

int main()
{
    double x = 10;
    cout << "Ln calculado con la funcion en <cmath>" << endl
    << "ln(10) = " << log(x) << endl;

    cout << "Ln calculado con funcion propia" << endl;
    cout << "ln(10) = " << log_mac(x) << endl;
}
double log_mac(double x)
{
    double resp = 0;

    for(int n = 1 ; n <= x ; n++)
    {
        double dividendo = pow(-1, n+1);
        double divisor = n;
        double multiplicador = pow(x, n);
        double temp = (dividendo / divisor) * multiplicador;

        //cout << dividendo << endl;

        resp += temp;
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Por lo que he leido, el metodo que usas solo sirve para valores entre -1 y  1 puedes ver la wikipedia [`Los polinomios de Taylor para ln(1 + x) únicamente proporcionan aproximaciones precisas en el rango −1 < x ≤ 1. Nótese que, para x > 1, los polinomios de Taylor de mayor grado son pésimas aproximaciones.`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo_natural). Lo otro.. la cantidad de ciclos que debe dar el for, está dado por la precicion que necesitas, no por la x, debes poner `for(int n = 1 ; n <= PRECICION ; n++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la función

[image: funcion]

[En wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation)

Se puede calcular de la siguiente forma para valores `0 < x < 2`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double log_mac(double);

int main()
{
    double x = 0.2;
    cout << "Ln calculado con la funcion en <cmath>" << endl
    << "ln(10) = " << log(x) << endl;

    cout << "Ln calculado con funcion propia" << endl;
    cout << "ln(10) = " << log_mac(x) << endl;
}

double log_mac(double x){
    double resp = 0;
    int iteraciones = 10;

    for(int n = 1 ; n <= iteraciones ; n++){
        resp += pow(-1, n + 1) * pow(x - 1.0, n) / n;
    }

    return resp;
}
```

Fuera del rango que mencioné antes, la aproximación se vuelve inútil:

[image: imagen]

Puedes ver los siguientes links útiles.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo_natural
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_de_Mercator
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-algorithm-is-used-by-computers-to-calculate-logarithms